# .NET Framework 4 Client Profile + System.Web.dll?

Tags: .net, dll, .net-client-profile, system.web

I'm currently developing an application for .NET 4 Client Profile, as this is the version that will be present on most home computers through Windows Update.

However, I cannot add a reference to `System.Web.dll` as it does not exist in this version - what should I do?

Is it a good idea to deploy System.Web.dll along with my application, or won't that work? I really need HTTP connections and all, so I cannot modify my application as a workaround. Is targeting my application to .NET 4 (no client profile) perhaps a possibility or will that just not work on computers with only the Client Profile?

Comment: **Do not deploy `System.Web.dll` as a standalone file with your project.** Require the user to install the full .NET Framework. Include this in your installer and no one will care.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> NET 4 Client Profile, as this is the
>   version that will be present on most
>   home computers through Windows Update

Not really. .NET 4 (client profile or not) currently isn't present on any pre-Windows 10 installation by default. For example, Windows 7 comes with .NET 3.5 SP1, not .NET 4.0. There may be a windows update, but it is optional.

Therefore, you might as well target the full .NET 4 framework.

The link between operating systems and .NET framework versions can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx). The checkmarks indicate that a version is available out of the box, plus sign means it can be installed.

Also note that 4.5, 4.6 and 4.6.1 are all in-place updates, meaning that a system with any of those is also considered to have 4.0.

Comment: You see it under "Optional updates". And that is afaik 4.0 client profile.

Answer (score 3):

If you are targeting .NET 4.0 and not .NET 4.0 Client Profile you should add that as a [prerequisite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). This will allow it to be installed when you install your application.

You can still use [Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w48w47c.aspx) if you run .NET 4.0 Client Profile, they are located in `System.Net`. You *only* want `System.Web` when the following applies:

> The System.Web namespace supplies
>   classes and interfaces that enable
>   browser-server communication. This
>   namespace includes the HttpRequest
>   class, which provides extensive
>   information about the current HTTP
>   request; the HttpResponse class, which
>   manages HTTP output to the client; and
>   the HttpServerUtility class, which
>   provides access to server-side
>   utilities and processes. System.Web
>   also includes classes for cookie
>   manipulation, file transfer, exception
>   information, and output cache control.

Comment: I get an error stating that the type `HttpCookieCollection` cannot be found - even after adding `System.Net.dll`. Anyway, is it a possibility to deploy `System.Web.dll` along ith my application?

Comment: It might have other dependencies as well. Change the target framework to .NET 4.0 ( full ) instead of Client Profile.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just wanting to use the HttpWebRequest, it is available in the client profile for .Net 4.

Here's an example that you can try, just create a new console app using the .Net 4 Client Profile and paste this into Program.cs...

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            using (var s = response.GetResponseStream())
            using( var sr = new StreamReader(s))
            {
                Console.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

You asked about HttpCookieCollection in one of your comments. It seems that HttpWebRequest uses a CookieContainer to store the cookies.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you deploy the copy of the `System.Web.dll` to the client that won't solve the problem. And the problem is: you can't link to the assemblies compiled for .NET 4 profile (not client) from the assembly that compiled for .NET 4 Client profile. The only solution is to target your assembly to the not client profile.

The [MSDN Page about .NET Framework Client Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx).